# Adding terms to Term Sets

Tags: 2010, term-store

I am trying to avoid the use of creating folders within a document library when migrating a library from SP2007 to SP2010.

Currently the library has folders that define the "clients". I would like to migrate that into a term set that contains all the clients, however I want that term set to be open to additional terms (aka Clients).

I realize that I can set the termset to be "open" and allow the addition of new items through the term store management tool however is there a way for the end user to add new terms without gaining access to the term store mgmt tool?

Comment: Do you do your taxonomy fields programmtically? XML definition?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but I am pretty sure we do not create the taxonomies programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a site column of type managed metadata, select "Allow Fill-in Choices" as "Yes". This would allow users to add new terms while selecting terms in the edit properties screen of the document. Note this would work only after you marked the termset "Open".